# Rails multiselect with static hash - how to save values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

In Rails 4, I have the following structure:

**User Model**

```
has_many :user_languages
```

**User_language model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

In my user view, I then have the following:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
 <%=f.select("user_languages", languages, {selected: "EN"}, {:multiple => true} )%>
<% end %>
```

I would like the user to select the languages he/she fluently speaks and save them in the database, in the user_language table. For each language, we would add a row to this table.

Knowing that languages is a static hash/array, not a table in the db, how can I save these values to the database? This method simply does not work, nothing is saved in the db, even after whitelisting them in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) on the column:

```
serialize :languages, Hash
```

BTW, from where you showing the languages to users as dropdown? I mean from where you fetch the dropdown contents? Do you store the `languages` in any global variable somewhere in your application?

I got a better solution. You create a new table for `languages`.
As you've mentioned user can have many languages, so the new association can be:

```
class User 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :languages 
end
class Language 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
end
```

It'll solve your problem and also it is very neat.

Comment: I'm fetching the dropdown content (languages) from a global variable somewhere in my application. I'd like to avoid a table if possible. Also, I don't like serialize because I won't be able to easily search for users speaking certain languages.

Comment: @Mike, You're using a table named `user_languages`. As you're using a table then why don't you want to use my approach? It'll also need a table and a join table. 
BTW, if you don't want to serialize then there is only the other option left as you want to use the data for searching.